# How to efficiently push new data to frontend without page reload or timer

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to have two screen actively mirror image each other from the opposite side of the building.

I currently have two frontend devices running Wordpress that have an `on` and `off` switch on both:

[image]
[image]
At the current moment I have a `<meta content="http-refresh=60">` running on both screens. My issue
running it this way is that because the interval is at 60 seconds, there is a bit of time to for error
to occur. If one user sets the setting to `off` and then the other user would be doubling up the same
action as their screen hasnt reflected correctly (lights on and off are just an example for this 
question)

I tried getting into `wp-api` and the `heartbeat-api` but I cannot find answers for the issues around
JSON not parsing correctly.

---

***Question of topic***

So I want to create an ajax pull similar to the meta-refresh, but there is already an ajax call on the 
form so I'm running into conflicts.

Current AJAX

```html
<form id="form">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="mb_user_location" value="on">On</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="mb_user_location" value="off">Off</label>
    <input hidden name="mb_user_id" value="<? get_current_user_id(); ?>">
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#form').change(function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        var mbformdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            method:         "POST",
            data:           mbformdata,
            contentType:    false,
            processData:    false,
            success:        function(a) { $( "#response" ).show().html(a); },
            complete:       function(a) { setTimeout(function(){ $(".mbsuccessmessage").slideUp(); }, 5000); }
            error:          function(b){ console.log(b); }
        });
    });
});
```

```php
$mb_location_set    = isset( $_POST['mb_user_location'] ) ? $_POST['mb_user_location']  : '';
$mb_location_userID = isset( $_POST['mb_user_id']       ) ? $_POST['mb_user_id']        : '';

// if there was empty data
if( empty( $mb_location_userID ) || empty( $mb_location_set ) ) {
    die( 'Something went wrong. Please try again' );

// otherwise set the location
} else {
    update_user_meta( $mb_location_userID, 'mb_user_location_current',  $mb_location_set );
    die( 'Location saved' );
}
```

Now I want to add another ajax call that will ask the server what the setting is, and update the interface
if it different to what is displayed.

I currently have the following:

```js
mb_send_request();

function mb_send_request() {
    var mbajaxdata = new FormData($('#form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        method:         "POST",
        data:           mbajaxdata,
        contentType:    false,
        processData:    false,
        success:        function() { console.log('success - ajax'); },
        complete:       function() { setInterval(mb_send_request, 15000); console.log('ajax - completed'); },
        error:          function(b){ console.log(b); }
    });
}
```

But I dont know at this point how to implement the two ajax calls on the same form, without conflicting
and to pass the PHP validation again.

Comment: You can use Cookies to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling data from server at a certain interval would still create delays and be unreliable, even if you do it every second. You should look into publish/subscribe service  [ably channels](https://www.ably.io/channels) or [pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com). Those are the first 2 from the top of my head, I am sure there are more alternatives. Usually such services are paid, but some of them offer free plans for low volume customers.

If you decide to go publish/subscribe way, there are again a few ways you can accomplish our goal.

- You can do everything in javascript, avoiding the need to connect to your php script altogether. In such case all the communication would be done through message service provider. You would have to make both front end apps publishers and subscribers at the same time. When the state changes on one of the clients, you publish a message to the channel, which is delivered to all other clients (subscribers of the channel). The clients change their state according to the contents of the message.
- Alternatively, on each state change you can submit the form and send it to your php script, which can act like a central "hub" which maintains the current state of the image. In such case you would make PHP script the "publisher" and all javascript clients "subscirbers". The rest is very similar: php script sends a message to all channel subscribers, which change their state according to the message content.

The PHP solution would have an advantage of knowing the state during page load, which helps for the initial sync of all the clients.

You should be aware that even though publish/subscribe service works almost in "real time" (it will probably take around 30-50ms for the message to get delivered), there is still a possibility of race conditions. 2 clients can change their state (image touched) almost at the same time (say a microsecond difference). Client A might expect to go from "on" to "off" state, and client B might expect to go from "on" to "off" state, but since there are actually 2 events happening and neither of the clients is aware of that, they might both end up with the "on" state in the end (depends how you handle the messages). The good part is that in your scenario such conditions are quite easy to detect and you can decide what to do about it: force all clients to the latest state silently or throw an error explaining that their app went out of sync for a moment.

Comment: as much as i didn’t want to hear it, you’re right. i’m looking into these solutions now or socket.io

Answer (score 1):

You can write a set interval that retrieves data and updates html in place instead.

using a header refresh is never recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify to code related to form submission, you can call your second method inside the listener :

```
$(function() {
$('#form').change(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    mb_send_request();
    var mbformdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);

...
});});
```

If you can't modify the code, you can listen the "change" event another time (you can have multiple listener on multiple event).

```
$('#form').change(function(a) {
    mb_send_request();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Wordpress is the best tool for the job here.

If it has to be browser based the cleanest thing would be using WebSockets, and a second bet would be using something like MQTT.

Something needs to say "You have data available" or ask "Do I have data available" there's just no way around that. It then becomes a tradeoff between throughput and latency.